# How to treat "too localized" questions?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Regarding, the current change about the available flag options (i.e. “too localized is no longer an option in the closing dialog):

Sometimes, questions "too localized" do not fit under other reasons (as off-topic, etc).

Like [SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185102/responding-to-your-too-localized-concerns), is it worthwhile to collect examples (looking forward improving "on topic" guidelines) of what would fit as former "too localized" concept and would not fit under the current other reasons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read in "[The War of the Closes](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/)" (which I highly recommend) about how each Stack Exchange community can now define its own Off Topic closure reasons and so I thought I would see what ours are:

[image]

I think the second option (a problem that can't be reproduced) is something that could be applied to a significant proportion of those that might formerly have been considered "too localized".

Answer (score 1):

I like to read and do reviews and I usually find that "too localized" as the reason mostly used as a flag. There is subjectivity in the matter and I personally believe that if a question involves using and implementation of GIS software and/or science then it is worthy of the attention of this site.

On the other hand, some  questions are about installing a specific version of a GIS software on a specific platform or using a particular GPS model with a particular software. Although, these type of questions involve GIS, the primary problem is not GIS related and therefore could be considered too localized.

On a third note, since some of the GIS software is purchased or not updated as frequently, questions involving postgis 1.4 or ArcGIS 9.3 will be relevant for a while as not everyone is purchasing or implementing upgrades. Dismissing a question because of the version of the software is unfair in my opinion

On a fourth note, this site is primarily about the usage of GIS software and systems vs mathematical, scientific, statistics, and GIScience, therefore it's harder to identify which questions could be considered as too localized

Comment: Thank's for your answer. I need to apologize with you, because I edited the question. I think your second paragraph is a good example of a subject that might underlie borderline in the future.

Comment: Although I agree that much of the daily traffic on this site is about mundane usage of GIS, I might disagree with that as a characterization of this site's purpose or the community's interests.  See http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383/what-is-this-site-about-really for a discussion of this point.